# how to run gtkmm application which does not block my main terminal and allow multi tasking

Tags: c++, multithreading, terminal, gtk

I am working on a project in which there is a main program which runs in an infinite loop and executes the command given into terminal and will exit the loop on "exit command". This main program is not at all related to GTK. Now i have implemented a command for this main program which initiates a gtk application. Now the problem is that my main program get hang up and is not processing further commands till the GTK application is running.This is obvious because on starting application we starts a GTK main loop which only exit on closing the application.

So is there anyway so that my Gtk application will start in new terminal and allow my main program to process further commands?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about GTK specifically, but *generally* you may want to run your command polling loop in a different thread of execution than your eventhandler Gui.

You can execute a task on a new thread using the thread facilites in the standard library like this:

```
// Example function.
void func(int arg1, double arg2) {
    /* Do something... */
}

int main() {
    std::thread t{func, 1, 2.0}; // Call func with args in new thread.

    /* Continue doing things in current thread. */

    t.join(); // Wait for thread to finish before exit.
}
```

Make sure to *synchronize* access to any data used by both threads.